# Not able to install full text search on sql server 2016

Tags: sql-server

So I have came across an issue . I want to enable full text search on my SQL server 2016 .I tried to enable it but the option was "grayed out" so I checked whether I have full text installed on the server and found out that i don't . I went to add the feature but am unable to because the feature is not listed in the features tab and ever other feature is installed . How can I Enable / Install Full text search on SQL server 2016 .

Comment: Make sure you are running SQL Server 2016 Express _with advanced services_.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid Thanks a lot bro that worked for me:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ability to do full text searches is available with SQL Server Express *with advanced services* and not with the normal version of SQLSE.

Make sure you have installed the correct version.